# How can I position this drupal block?

Tags: css, drupal, position, css-position

I have created a block for my first client's website, im newish to Drupal and web development. On [their contact page](http://mediamatterstechnology.com/contact), I would like to position the block with the contact details to the right of the contact form which I have floated left.

I've tried floating the block right and position with absolute positioning, however when I resize the window it doesn't look right, all the text sqaushes up.

What I need is to move the block down, which I know I will have to put some css into the responsive css files to make the block move under the form when the window is resized but how should I position this text next to the form?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can float that block to the right and give both blocks a specific width

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I float to the right the block just floats right underneath the form, I need it next to the form. It still does this when I give both the form and the block a specified width.

Comment: there are two options: 1) You set the html code of the block with contact detail above the form code. 2) You float both blocks (form left, contact right) and give both a specific width

Answer (score 0):

Which theme are you using? Isn't there a sidebar block you can position the contact details in? You shouldn't need to do any floating to achieve this, but rather the positioning of the blocks should be happening at the theme layout and template level.